# symbol lookup error: .so.2 undefined symbol

Tags: symbols

How to solve this undefined symbol.

> odroid@odroid:~/flycapture.2.9.3.43_armhf/bin$ sudo ./FlyCap2
>   ./FlyCap2: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libflycapturegui.so.2: undefined symbol: *ZN5Gnome5Glade3Xml6createERKSsRKN4Glib7ustringES7*

```
odroid@odroid:~/flycapture.2.9.3.43_armhf/bin$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep fly

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libflycapture.so.2 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libflycapturegui.so.2 is not a symbolic link

libflycapture.so.2 -> libflycapture.so.2.9.3.43
libflycapturegui.so.2 -> libflycapturegui.so.2.9.3.43
```

---

```
odroid@odroid:~/flycapture.2.9.3.43_armhf/bin$ ls -lah /usr/lib | grep fly

-rw-r--r--   1 root root 473K Jul 13 13:26 libflycapturegui.so
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 473K Jul 13 13:26 libflycapturegui.so.2
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 473K Jul 13 13:26 libflycapturegui.so.2.9.3.43
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3.3M Jul 13 13:26 libflycapture.so
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3.3M Jul 13 13:26 libflycapture.so.2
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3.3M Jul 13 13:26 libflycapture.so.2.9.3.43
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we can look at the information available, and use that to begin searching.  As you're using Linux, it's most likely a GCC or Clang mangled symbol, which gives us a good starting place: We can look for information on the GNU mangling schemes.

Next, look for patterns in the symbol.  There are multiple one-number-multiple-letters strings, where the number is the total number of letters in the string; this likely indicates that these are names.

Considering that, we can take the symbol `ZN5Gnome5Glade3Xml6createERKSsRKN4Glib7ustringES7`, and break it down into:

```
Z
N
5Gnome
5Glade
3Xml
6create
E
R
K
S
s
R
K
N
4Glib
7ustring
E
S
7
```

Now, according to the GNU3-4 mangling scheme described in the [PDF "Calling Conventions"](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) (pg.38), names are encoded as:

```
<public name>    ::= _Z <qualified name>
<qualified name> ::= N [<simple name>]<sup>∞</sup><sub>2</sub> E
    There are a minimum of 2 "simple name" symbols.
<simple name>    ::= <name length> <name>
    "Name length" is a decimal number indicating the length of "name".
Nested names are listed inwards, with the leftmost one being the outermost.
```

We can use this to piece together a partial symbol, and its meaning:

```
Symbol: _ZN5Gnome5Glade3Xml6createE
Means : The symbol's qualified name is "Gnome::Glade::Xml::create".
Note  : At least one underscore appears to have been dropped by the error message.
```

Considering the junk after it, and the name itself, this is a function symbol.  So, considering that, we can just feed the symbol to Google, and get [a link to the class' reference.](http://www.gtkmm.org/gnomemm2/reference/html/classGnome_1_1Glade_1_1Xml.html)  According to this link, the function is defined as:

```
Class  :   Gnome::Glade::Xml
Section: "Static Public Member Functions"
Full declaration:
    static Glib::RefPtr< Xml >
    create (const std::string &filename, const Glib::ustring &root=Glib::ustring(),
            const Glib::ustring &domain=Glib::ustring())
```

To double-check, we can determine what the function's mangled name would be, using that parameter list:

```
static Glib::RefPtr< Xml >
Gnome::Glade::Xml::create (const std::string &filename,
                           const Glib::ustring &root=Glib::ustring(),
                           const Glib::ustring &domain=Glib::ustring());
```

Directly putting this in a simple C++ program (using dummy classes for `Glib::RefPtr<T>`, `Glib::ustring`, and `Gnome::Glade::Xml`), then outputting `typeid(Gnome::Glade::Xml::create).name()` to `cout` didn't generate the correct symbol, which suggests a change in either the mangling scheme or the ABI.  More specifically, `std::string` was mangled as `NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`, instead of the expected `Ss`.  After [a bit of digging around](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html), I discovered that this is due to a change in GCC 5.1 and later versions, where the macro `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` indicates to use the new `string` (and new name) instead of the old one.  This gives a likely indication of the cause of the problem, as well (see the end of this post).

So, considering this, it would be best to mangle the function's name by hand, using the old scheme, and see if it matches the symbol.

```
<public name> ::= <simple or qualified name> [<parameter type>]<sup>∞</sup><sub>1</sub>
    There is a minimum of 1 "parameter type" symbols.

Name      : Gnome::Glade::Xml::create
Parameters:
    const std::string&   : RKSs
        "RK" is "Reference (R), const (K)", and "Ss" is a special symbol for std::string.
    const Glib::ustring& : RK4Glib7ustringE
        "RK" is followed by the type's "qualified name".
    const Glib::ustring& : RK4Glib7ustringE
```

As the third parameter is a duplicate of the third, it uses abbreviation rules, where `Sx_` is an abbreviated symbol.  According to the PDF, each user-defined type name, namespace name, and non-simple type is assigned an abbreviation, but the entity name itself is not.  Therefore...

```
S0_ : 5Gnome
S1_ : 5Glade
S2_ : 3Xml
S3_ : Ss
S4_ : RKSs
S5_ : 4Glib
S6_ : 7ustring
S7_ : RK4Glib7ustringE
```

And thus, the third parameter is `S7_`.  Considering this, the final symbol is:

```
Name          : _ZN5Gnome5Glade3Xml6createE
Parameter list: RKSsRKN4Glib7ustringES7_
    Parameters:
        RKSs              : const std::string&
        RKN4Glib7ustringE : const Glib::ustring&
        S7_               : const Glib::ustring&
Symbol        : _ZN5Gnome5Glade3Xml6createERKSsRKN4Glib7ustringES7_
    Two underscores were apparently dropped somewhere, one on each end.
```

Feeding this to the utility site [Demangler.com](http://demangler.com/) results in the following demangled symbol:

```
Gnome::Glade::Xml::create(std::string const&, Glib::ustring const&, Glib::ustring const&)
```

As the PDF states that the return type isn't included in the mangling scheme for normal functions, this appears to be correct.

---

Now, as mentioned above, the ABI was changed, resulting in changes to the mangling scheme and/or the library typenames.  So, to check this, I did a little testing.

```
// main.cpp
//#undef  _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
//#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0

//#include <iostream>
//#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>


namespace Glib {
    template<typename T>
    class RefPtr {};

    class ustring {};
}

namespace Gnome {
    namespace Glade {
        class Xml {
          public:
            static Glib::RefPtr< Xml >
            create (const std::string &filename,
                    const Glib::ustring &root=Glib::ustring(),
                    const Glib::ustring &domain=Glib::ustring());
        };
    }
}

Glib::RefPtr< Gnome::Glade::Xml >
Gnome::Glade::Xml::create (const std::string &filename,
                           const Glib::ustring &root /*=Glib::ustring()*/,
                           const Glib::ustring &domain /*=Glib::ustring()*/) {
                               return Glib::RefPtr<Gnome::Glade::Xml>();
                           }

int main() {
//    std::cout << typeid(const std::string&).name() << std::endl;
//    std::cout << typeid(Gnome::Glade::Xml::create).name() << std::endl;

//    std::cout << typeid(std::string).name() << std::endl;
}
```

By taking this code, I first used `typeid` to output the function symbol, then commented out the first two `#include`s and the body of `main()`, compiled the file with the `-c` compiler option, and output the symbol list with `nm main.o`.  While `typeid` didn't match the symbol, the names displayed by `nm` were:

```
// With macros commented out:
_ZN5Gnome5Glade3Xml6createERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKN4Glib7ustringESD_

// With macros active:
_ZN5Gnome5Glade3Xml6createERKSsRKN4Glib7ustringES7_
```

As the second one is identical to the symbol mentioned in the error message, this indicates that the mangling scheme is still the same, and thus the solution to the problem is:

**Either the object files you're attempting to link were compiled with different versions of GCC (or whichever GCC-compatible compiler you were using), or one was compiled with the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro set to `0` and the other wasn't.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to install flycapture on arch linux.  Eventually I figured out there is a more recent version of flycapture available (2.11.3.121) that doesn't have that problem.